# Magento Payment method page blank after enabling compilation

Tags: php, magento, paypal, magento-1.8

For PayPal multi currency issue, used "Web_Ppfix" extension which gives a good result as well.
But once, compilation is enabled, menu "SYSTEM CONFIGURATION >> PAYMENT METHODS" gives a blank page, so cannot change any thing in payment settings.
When compilation is disabled, the Payment Method page works as usual.

Anyone knows why this happens and is there a workaround?

Comment: This is certainly not a solution but.....you might want to look at whether it's worth just turning the compilation off and leaving it off. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19231/is-it-safe-to-run-magento-compiler

Comment: You're on 1.8, the compiler has become increasingly less useful at speeding up Magento since 1.6 due to code optimization done by the Magento team. Enable `opcache`, ditch using the compiler. You're only one module install away from having to do that anyway and `opcache` gives a far better speed boost.